# Style feature by tag in postgesql by geoserver

Tags: postgis, geoserver, style

I have a geometry table say its name is "tb_feature", and each feature have multiple tags which are saved in table "tb_tags", and the relationship is saved by another table "tb_feature_tag".

Example data:

tb_feature:

```
id  the_geom
1   xxxx
```

tb_tags

```
1  primary
2  road
3  uncompleted
```

tb_feature_tag

```
feature_id  tag_id
1           1
1           2
```

Now I want to style the feature based on there tags in geoserver. Generally the features are styled by different fields which are saved in the same table with the feature.  But the fields used for `Rule-based` styleing (tags in my example) are saved in another table.

How to handle this kind of situation?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of representing features in GeoServer [simple](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/app-schema/complex-features.html#simple-features) and [complex](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/app-schema/complex-features.html#id1), you can construct the sort of 1-many joins that you want only in the complex features side. To use complex features you will need to add the [`app schema` extension](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/app-schema/index.html) which will allow you to use [xpath expressions](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/app-schema/wms-support.html) in your SLD file to specify how to style features.

If you want to go with simple features then you could probably construct a [view](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/database/postgis.html#publishing-a-postgis-view) on your tables with some sort of combined tag value that can be used in a filter inside the SLD.